# Odoo: open full model page from add line in a one2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I made a custom model and i have a one2many field where i click on "add new line" then "search more" to look for the item i want to add  just like the picture below

[image]

What I want is to click on "add new line", and the whole products page appear without having to go throw the previous process

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you update your questions with your efforts?

Comment: this is where i stopped, i tried googling it, but no clue

Comment: One more thing, any idea how can i put filters to the opened widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `ListRenderer` and override [_onAddRecord](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/static/src/js/section_and_note_fields_backend.js#L95) to open a search more view using a condition in context.

The following code adds a new widget to open `search more...` link and select many records.

```js
odoo.define('stack_overflow.open_list_view', function (require) {

    "use strict";
    var pyUtils = require('web.py_utils');
    var dialogs = require('web.view_dialogs');
    var core = require('web.core');
    var _t = core._t;
    var fieldRegistry = require('web.field_registry');
    var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');

    var AddManyFieldOne2ManyRenderer = ListRenderer.extend({
        /**
         * It will returns the first visible widget that is editable
         *
         * @private
         * @returns {Class} Widget returns first widget
         */
        _getFirstWidget: function () {
            var record = this.state.data[this.currentRow];
            var recordWidgets = this.allFieldWidgets[record.id];
            var firstWidget = _.chain(recordWidgets).filter(function (widget) {
                var isLast =
                    widget.$el.is(':visible') &&
                    (
                        widget.$('input').length > 0 || widget.tagName === 'input' ||
                        widget.$('textarea').length > 0 || widget.tagName === 'textarea'
                    ) &&
                    !widget.$el.hasClass('o_readonly_modifier');
                return isLast;
            }).first().value();
            return firstWidget;
        },

        add_rows: function (lines, field_name) {
            var self = this;
            if (lines.length > 0) {
                self.trigger_up('add_record', {
                    context: [{ [field_name]: lines[0] }],
                    forceEditable: "bottom",
                    allowWarning: true,
                    onSuccess: function () {
                        self.unselectRow();
                        lines.shift(); // Remove the first element after adding a line
                        self.add_rows(lines, field_name);
                    }
                });

            }
        },
        _onAddRecord: function (ev) {
            // we don't want the browser to navigate to a the # url
            ev.preventDefault();

            // we don't want the click to cause other effects, such as unselecting
            // the row that we are creating, because it counts as a click on a tr
            ev.stopPropagation();


            var self = this;
            // but we do want to unselect current row
            this.unselectRow().then(function () {
                var context = ev.currentTarget.dataset.context;
                if (context && pyUtils.py_eval(context).open_list_view) {
                    // trigger add_record to get field name and model
                    // you do not need to trigger add_record if you pass the field name and model in context
                    self.trigger_up('add_record', {
                        context: [{}],
                        onSuccess: function () {
                            var widget = self._getFirstWidget();
                            var field_name = 'default_' + widget.name;
                            var model = widget.field.relation;
                            self.unselectRow();
                            self._rpc({
                                model: model,
                                method: 'search',
                                args: [[]],
                            }).then(
                                function (result) {
                                    return new dialogs.SelectCreateDialog(self, _.extend({}, self.nodeOptions, {
                                        res_model: model,
                                        context: context,
                                        title: _t("Search: add lines"),
                                        initial_ids: result,
                                        initial_view: 'search',
                                        disable_multiple_selection: false,
                                        no_create: !self.can_create,
                                        on_selected: function (records) {
                                            self.add_rows(records.map(product => product.id), field_name);
                                        }
                                    })).open();
                                });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    self.trigger_up('add_record', { context: context && [context] });
                }
            });
        },
    });

    var AddManyFieldOne2Many = fieldRegistry.map.section_and_note_one2many.extend({
        /**
         * We want to use our custom renderer for the list.
         *
         * @override
         */
        _getRenderer: function () {
            if (this.view.arch.tag === 'tree') {
                return AddManyFieldOne2ManyRenderer;
            }
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        },
    });

    fieldRegistry.add('add_many_one2many', AddManyFieldOne2Many);
});
```

To use it define the widget attribute of the one2Many field to

```
<field name="field_name" widget="add_many_one2many"...
```

And add the following option to the tree view of the one2Many field

```
<create string="Open list view" context="{'open_list_view': True}"/>
```

Comment: no not really, can you explain more? or how to do it?

Comment: You have just to add the widget and use it. You are welcome to ask for more explanation

Comment: I can't you thank you enough, you're a genius, thank you alot, it worked

Comment: Hello Kenly, i know it's been a long time since the last comment, but it suddenly stopped working after i removed the Invoicing module and didn't work again after reinstalling the said module, any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Check the log file or/and the browser console to see the error message.

Comment: I checked and it said ```web.assets_backend.js:1600 Missing widget:  add_many_one2many  for field product_ids of type one2many
_getFieldWidgetClass @ web.assets_backend.js:1600```, don't really know what's the issue here

Comment: i also found this error ```web.assets_common.js:91 Error while loading bearings_module.open_list_view: TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
    at web.assets_backend.js:5902
    at web.assets_common.js:91
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at processJob (web.assets_common.js:91)
    at Object.odoo.processJobs (web.assets_common.js:98)
    at web.assets_common.js:92```

Comment: after more investigation this is where it stops ```var AddManyFieldOne2Many = fieldRegistry.map.section_and_note_one2many.extend({

```

Comment: Sorry to reply too late.  I created a demo module, [one2many_add_many](https://filebin.net/ytblpgxev4tzq15n). Try it and give me feedback

Comment: No need to be sorry and really thank you for your reply and help, i did install it, but don't know how to use it in my module

Comment: You have to copy the JS and the view files then add the view to the data entry in the manifest file. The module depends on the web module.

Comment: so i copy the js and view files to my module and add the view to the manifest file?

Comment: Yes. When I said add the view to the manifest file I mean add `'views/views.xml',` to the data entry in the manifest file.

Comment: I followed your instructions but still got the following ```basic_view.js:83 Missing widget:  add_many_one2many  for field offer_ids of type one2many``` ```error: Some modules could not be started
boot.js:195 Failed modules:           ["one2many_add_many.open_list_view"]
boot.js:207 Debug:                    {one2many_add_many.open_list_view: {…}}```

Comment: The code is tested on Odoo 12. Did you use the same Odoo version?

Comment: Yes i tried it on Odoo 12, does invoicing have to be installed?

Comment: No, it depends on the web module. It seems that the JS code is not loaded.

Comment: would upgrading to a newer version like 14, solve the problem?

Comment: Upgrading to a newer version is not the solution

Comment: the other thing is, would it work on newer versions?

Comment: I tried debugging with assets, and i got this error ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined
    at Class.setup (view_dialogs.js:376)```, i tried searching for it and i got no answers that would solve it

Comment: Please create a demo module to reproduce the same error and send me a link.

Comment: Hello Kenly, it's been a long time i know, but if you may, any idea why this code wouldn't work on odoo 15?

Comment: They rewrote the js framework code infrastructure in Odoo 15

Comment: what a shame, it worked perfectly in 12, what would you suggest i should study in order to create same effect in odoo 15

Comment: You check how to [extend](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/javascript_reference.html#creating-a-subclass) the `section_and_note_one2many` and [ListRenderer](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js#L21) widgets. The code above define a new section and note one2many widget with a custom renderer

Answer (score 0):

Salam Ahmed 
you can create a function that take you directly to product page and assigned to a button like in wizard's when you click to create a new view or get data from another view or page

Comment: but if i make it this way, once i go to the products page, how's it gonna return the selected product to the one2many field again?